# Error Object undefined for Express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have setup an Express app. It seems that the global Error object is undefined.

`console.log(Error)`  gives 'undefined' ,
and `console.log(JSON.stringify(new Error('error message'))` gives `{}`

Since Error object is undefined I cannot return errors like this

```
return next( new Error( 'error message!' )
```

Is it possible that Error object is renamed or something? Is there a work around this?

(I used IntelliJ Idea to construct the express app.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong - it is **impossible** that `console.log(Error)` prints *undefined* while at the same time `console.log(JSON.stringify(new Error('error message'))` prints `{}` - this behaviour is mutually exclusive - you should see an error about *undefined is not a function*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error object is not undefined. If it was, this would throw a TypeError:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(new Error('error message')));
```

Instead, it is returning an empty object, because that is what V8 returns if you send an Error object into `JSON.stringify()`. I'm not sure if that's a feature or a bug or neither, but regardless, this will give you the result you expect:

```
console.log(new Error('error message'));
```